# Can I edit background of class slideshow using CSS?

Tags: css, class

I have a image slideshow with descriptor underneath.
Can I edit the background from grey to something else by using a code similar to this

```
class overlay-below {
  background: #EECEFD;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Hope you're gaining an interest in being a contributing member of the community. As an FYI, if an answer to your question addresses your issue, you may want to consider accepting it as correct. It's considered both helpful and polite to do so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is off:

```
.overlay-below {
  background: #EECEFD;
}
```

Consider the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="container" id="main_page">
    <div class="column" id="profile">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="status">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

In the absence of ***any*** other markup, the following are equivalent:

```
.container {}
.container#main_page {}
#main_page{}
```

As are these:

```
.container .column {}
.container#main_page .column {}
#main_page .column {}
.column {}
```

As are these:

```
.container .column#profile {}
.container#main_page .column#profile {}
#main_page .column#profile {}
.column#profile {}

.container #profile {}
.container#main_page #profile {}
#main_page #profile {}
#profile {}
```

As you can see, there's a lot of scoping going on in CSS (and these declarations are not even exhaustive of the possibilities for this markup alone). Bear in mind, also, that whether or not you can actually adjust the color of your slideshow background is dependent on any number of factors, including (but not limited to) whether it's acceptable in whatever slideshow library you're using.